# Can I set frame of particular view programatically even if Auto Layout is enabled?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios8, autolayout

Suppose I am having a view controller A having 5 views inside it like labels, buttons. I have set constraint to 4 views. But, for 5th view, case is different. In portrait, I need different x,y positions and height and width. In landscape, I need different x,y positions and height and width. So, it is not possible to define constraints for that because it's a custom. I will only have to set frame programmatically wherever I wanted my view to be placed in different orientation.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: 5th_view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
and then set the frame.

Comment: I will write the code you mentioned in the method called on orientation change. Right ? And please write a "answer", so that I can upvote and accept if it worked...

Comment: write this code in orientation change. ha ha..... no need of upvote.....    
just try this code and let me know if it worked.

Comment: It worked like a charm. So, in future, if client wants particular view to be placed at custom position even-though constraints are added to other views, I can use this. Right ?

Comment: Glad it worked. :-) yes you can use this.   Happy Coding :-) :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot "Agent Chocks" !!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76336/discussion-between-pratik-and-agent-chocks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After detecting the `orientation` you can use the `IBOutlets` of your connected `control` to set the `frame` for example :

```
[myView setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
```

I hope this helps you.

**EDIT**

first create a constraint in the story board or your IB then create an outlet for that constraint for ex :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *viewHeightConstraint;
```

then change this constraint programmatically like :

```
self.viewHeightConstraint.constant = 40;
```

Comment: I already have tried it. But, as Auto Layout is enabled and I have added constraints to remaining 4 views, the frame change (programmatically) on 5th view is not working.

Comment: My question is not on how I can get device resolution or orientation or the place to change frame.

Comment: @Ahsan Autolayout is enabled, you need to convert it to constraints.

Comment: Another possibility can be that you set the constraints in the xib file or the story board, and change those constraints programmatically. See my edited answer

Comment: I don't want to use any constraint for that 5th view. I just want to change the frame as I needed programmatically...

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
Add this to your viewcontroller,and use it to monitor your device orientation,than change your 5th view frame

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator{

}
```

**Option 2**

In viewDidLoad add

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(change:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Then in this function you can monitor orientation change

```
-(void)change:(UIDeviceOrientation)orientation{

}
```

In dealloc,remove it

```
-(void)dealloc{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Can you give me brief idea about option 1 ? I mean what I will write in that method ?